# Trocar "Web Browser" vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, vb.net

Estou querendo alterar o navegador padrão do visual studio, gostaria de utilizar outro para rodar alguns scripts que estão com problemas no internet explorer. Gostaria de sugestões e exemplos de como fazer isso. Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Meu projeto é em Windows Forms, utilizo o navegador padrão do visual studio para executar alguns gráficos em java script, só que tive alguns problemas recentemente e vou precisar trocar o navegador.
Enfim, vou executar esse navegador dentro do próprio form.

Comment: não sei se funciona no vb, mas C#, pelo nuget você pode instalar o `CefSharp` baseado no projeto chromium. Foi a única solução que consegui para o mesmo cenário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem algumas opções, uma delas é o que o Rovann citou, pelo que pesquisei vale a pena fazer um teste no Gecko, é baseado no Mozilla. Colocarei um code sample em C# (para vb.net você nao terá dificuldades para converter)

[CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp)

[Dotnetbrowser](https://www.teamdev.com/dotnetbrowser) (pago)

[GeckoFX](https://www.codeground.net/coding/using-geckofx-instead-of-net-webbrowser-control/)

```
 GeckoWebBrowser browser;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var app_dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
        Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(Path.Combine(app_dir, "xulrunner"));

        browser = new GeckoWebBrowser();

        browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.browser.Name = "browser";

        this.Controls.Add(browser);
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado Thiago.
Vou verificar e fazer uns testes!

Abraço.